# Visual Studio Code right click menu opens in wrong location on the screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

While editing a `.c` file I noticed that the context menu is relatively long and opens in a position a few pixels left of where it should open. If you right click and release immediately, it just selects whatever command coincides the mouse cursor. Here is the GIF showing that:

[image]

Where should I fix this problem?

```
Version: 1.76.2
Commit: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
Date: 2023-03-14T17:57:21.103Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-0.deb11.2-amd64
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: What OS and desktop environment are you on?

Comment: OS: Debian Bullseye, DE: XFCE4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug and fixed in version before or in `1.83.0`.

```
Version: 1.83.0
Commit: e7e037083ff4455cf320e344325dacb480062c3c
Date: 2023-10-03T16:11:49.843Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-0.deb11.2-amd64
```